# Formatting CSV with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm taking form data and writing it to a csv file on the server. I keep running into the same type of issues and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Either the column headers repeat with each entry, or each additional submission writes on the same row. Also, how would I take the $_POST data and populate the csv? I have to declare it twice to get this to work to this point. Here is what I have that somewhat works.

```
<?php
   //this is just for the post data, but I'm having to declare the key/values again below. I'm sure this is wrong.
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   //rest of the form inputs go here same as $email
   //some server side validation builds an 'error' array

   if(!isset($error) {
        $del = ", ";
        //this is where I have to repeat the post data key/values
        $data[1] = $_POST['email'];
        $data[2] = $_POST['FirstName'];
        $data[3] = $_POST['LastName'];
        $data[4] = $_POST['Address'];
        $data[5] = $_POST['City'];
        $data[6] = $_POST['Country'];
        $data[7] = $_POST['State'];
        $data[8] = $_POST['Phone1'];
        $data[9] = $_POST['password'];

        $file = fopen("Registration.csv", "a");
        //$data is the column headers that won't behave
        $data = "Email, First Name, Last Name, Address, City, Country, State, Phone, Password
        ".implode($del, $data);
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);  
   }
?>
```

Comment: Try using [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of trying to write it out yourself. Pass in the headers first, then the data.

Comment: http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/ great tutorial

Comment: That is a good tutorial. However I'm not getting data from db, but from a form and I want to write to the server not download file.

Comment: Currently, you're always repeating the file's header, because you are always writing them. Working on a solution now.

Comment: Using fputcsv helped a lot - each entry is a new row. Now Im just repeating the header row as @ChrisHappy pointed out above.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign do a check to see if the file exists, if it exists, do not add headers as they would have been added in your first run of the script. Else, assume it is first run since the file has not been created and add headers into file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, try the following:

This code checks if the file is empty, and if it is, writes the headers.

```
$headers = "Email, First Name, Last Name, Address, City, Country, State, Phone, Password";
if (0 == filesize( $file_path )) {        
     fwrite($file, $headers);
}
```

```html
<?php
   $email = $_POST['email'];

   if(!isset($error) {
        $del = ", ";
        //this is where I have to repeat the post data key/values
        $data = array(
          $_POST['email'], //You can replace this with $email
          $_POST['FirstName'], //You can also replace this with the rest of the variables. It should make it cleaner and faster.
          $_POST['LastName'],
          $_POST['Address'],
          $_POST['City'],
          $_POST['Country'],
          $_POST['State'],
          $_POST['Phone1'],
          $_POST['password'],
        );

        $file = fopen("Registration.csv", "a");
        
        $headers = "Email, First Name, Last Name, Address, City, Country, State, Phone, Password";
        
        if (0 == filesize( "Registration.csv" )) {
          fwrite($file, $headers . "\n");
        }
        
        fputcsv($file, $data);
        fclose($file);  
   }
?>
```

Comment: It creates the headers, but no data in the rows below.

Comment: Close, but it repeated the form data as a header. So there is the correct header, the form data all in one row. The second row has the data under the correct header, and blank cells under the repeated for data in the header

Comment: Okay, added a new line after the headers. Having a hard time understanding the second problem... Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, wish I could just paste in what the result is. Basically, in row 1, you have the correct headers, then the form data. In the second row you have the form data under the correct headers from row1, then blank cells under the incorrect form data headers.

Comment: Got it sorted, the "\n" worked. Thank you, very sleek solution. Checking to see if the file existed in order to write the column headers was the part I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

```
$myfile = fopen("Registration.csv", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data = "Email, First Name, Last Name, Address, City, Country, State, Phone, Password
    ".implode($del, $data);

fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

i hope this helps

Comment: created a blank csv with two rows and two columns

Comment: you can remove implode from it.